# How to enablePlugins() for subprojects when using scala-js crossCompile?

Tags: sbt, scala.js

Note that this is not an IntelliJ error, and is present when running from SBT directly when starting `sbt` in the project:

```
C:\Users\brand\Documents\GitHub\scalajs-cross-compile-example\build.sbt:27: error: type mismatch;
 found   : sbt.Project
 required: sbt.internals.DslEntry
fooJVM.enablePlugins(SbtXjcPlugin)
```

I'm using the canonical example of the scala-js cross compile project with two changed lines ([on github](https://github.com/bbarker/scalajs-cross-compile-example/tree/213c304e801f72d4f5442083f2527daf7f491da7)).

As you can check, the only difference is that I added another plugin to plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-sbt.plugins" % "sbt-xjc" % "0.8")
```

And I added this line to the end of `buid.sbt`:

```
fooJVM.enablePlugins(SbtXjcPlugin)
```

Admittedly this is a bit of a contrived example, but I do have reasons for wanting to enable plugins only for JVM projects, which I can go into more detail if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not call anything on `fooJVM` (the [pitfalls](http://www.scala-js.org/api/sbt-scalajs/latest/#org.scalajs.sbtplugin.cross.CrossProject) section in the documentation explains that).

Instead, use `jvmConfigure`:

```
lazy val foo = crossProject.in(file(".")).
   // stuff
   jvmConfigure(_.enablePlugins(SbtXjcPlugin))
```

The reason you need to do this is that `enablePlugins` returns a new instance of `Project` that is modified. So `foo.jvm` and `fooJVM` are not the same project anymore.

However, as you'll probably notice, this is not why your build file fails: In your specific case, the build fails because sbt does not allow "bare" statements like this. This makes sense, since they do not do anything for the same reason: `enablePlugins` returns a new `Project` with the plugin enabled but does not alter the receiver.

Comment: Thanks! I think it should be `jvmConfigure` and not `configureJvm`, but the fact that you typed that up from memory is yet more impressive to an SBT newbie even with the typo!

Comment: Hahahahahahaha, it should be `jvmConfigure` indeed... You know, the peculiar thing is this: (1) I had the documentation open (2) I have *written* this code.